# Pass parameter value to action using RedirectToaction MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my action method in controller

```
public ActionResult RedirectToDemoView(string message)
{
    var model = new Error();
    model.Message = message;
    return this.View("Error", model);
}
```

How do I pass the parameter to this action from my view ( .cshtml) page using jquery ? Here is my code

```
redirectToAction('@Url.Action("RedirectToDemoView", "Audit" )',
    new { message:$(request.responseText).find('h2').eq(0).text() });
```

It is passing `null` value to `RedirectToDemoView` method.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var message = $(request.responseText).find('h2').eq(0).text();
var url = '@Url.Action("RedirectToDemoView", "Audit")?message=' + encodeURIComponent(message);
redirectToAction(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
redirectToAction('@Url.Content("~/Audit/RedirectToDemoView?message=")' 
                   + $(request.responseText).find('h2').eq(0).text());
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I wouldn't use this because you are assuming the pattern of your routes. If someone changes this in your routes registration this code will break. It's better to use the `Url.Action` helper instead.